# Problem with showing existance of countable family of Borel subsets, equivalence relation

Tags: functions, equivalence-relations, borel-sets

We assume existance of Borel function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with the condition that for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $$x\sim  y\iff f(x)=f(y).$$
How to show then an existance of countable family $\{A_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of Borel subsets $\mathbb{R}$, such that
$$x\sim y \iff \forall_n \ (x \in A_n \iff y \in A_n).$$
It seems to be logical but I have no idea how to write it down formally. This is my first problem.

The second is strongly connected with the first one, namely I need to show the opposite implication, i.e. if exists countable family $\{A_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of Borel subsets $\mathbb{R}$, such that
$$x\sim y \iff \forall_n \ (x \in A_n \iff y \in A_n),$$
then we can show that there exists  borel function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with the condition that for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $$x\sim  y\iff f(x)=f(y).$$

Every advice and help would be much appreciated, because I don't have any sensible ideas.

Comment: $\mathbb Q{}{}$

Comment: @John B I am not so into rules of this page. What does it mean? I guess it has nothing in common with rational numbers.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Yes, it is every measurable function

Comment: @Novice My comment is for John B. He made a meaningless comment (which even got upvoted) and I am asking him if he knows what this question is about. Your question is a good one and I am upvoting it.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Sorry I didn't notice that your question was directed to another person. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: How can we flag this very rude guy @KaviRamaMurthy?

Comment: So you can use my comment above to give a complete answer. By far, this is the best possible hint.

Comment: @Novice If $f=\sum \frac {1_{A_n}} {2^{n}}$ then $f$ is a Borel function. Expansion of numbers in $[0,1]$ to base $2$ is 'almost' unique. If we had uniqueness then we could say $f(x)=f(y)$ iff $x$ and $y$ belong to the same $A_n$'s iff $x \sim y$. I am having trouble in completing  this because expansion to base $2$ is not unique. Some modification  of this $f$ (on dyadic rationals) should work.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Glad to know that you finally understood my hint, and provide a reply following exactly what I suggested (it remains to correct a basic mistake, I let you try to find what it is).